# Failure in initial objective function evaluation. LSQNONLIN cannot continue

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm working on curve fitting of two equations with common variable and arguments.  the code as below:

```
    function F = myfun(params,c, tt, hh)
    F =[tt - params(2) - params(3) ./ (1 + params(3).^2 .* params(1).^2 .* (2.* pi.* freqs).^2),...
        hh +((2.* pi.* freqs) .* params(4) - params(3).^2 * params(1) .* (2.* pi.* freqs) ./ (1 + params(3).^2 .* params(1).^2 .* (2.* pi.* freqs).^2))];
end
```

the curve fitting is:

```
lb = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1e10, 0, 0];
up = [inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf,inf];
params0 = [ 6e-8, 1.07e-7, 15, 10, 27e10, 0.29, 0.43e-6];

% options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin,'Algorithm','trust-region-reflective');

params = lsqnonlin(@myfun, params0, lb, up);
```

the error is :

```
    Not enough input arguments.

Error in Untitled>myfun (line 98)
F =[real_new - params(2) - params(3) ./ (1 +
params(3).^2 .* params(1).^2 .* (2.* pi.*
freqs).^2),...

Error in lsqnonlin (line 206)
            initVals.F =
            feval(funfcn{3},xCurrent,varargin{:});

Error in Untitled (line 32)
params = lsqnonlin(@myfun, params0, lb, up);

Caused by:
    Failure in initial objective function
    evaluation. LSQNONLIN cannot continue.
```

I tried to check the defined function, it should be correct. 
how to deal with the errors? 
any help or suggestions are appreciated!

...................................

the  `Not enough input arguments` solved by change `myfun` (which has more arguments and more complex) shown as below:

```
myfun = @(params)[tt - params(2) - ((2.* pi.* freqs).^2.*params(5).^2.*params(3))./(params(3).^2 + (2.* pi.* freqs).^2.*params(5).^2)...
    -(params(4).*(1-(2.* pi.* freqs).^2.*params(1).*params(7).*params(6).*params(4))...
    + ((2.* pi.* freqs).*params(7).*params(6).*params(4)).*((2 * pi.* freqs).*params(7).*Rp+ (2 * pi.* freqs).*params(7).*params(6)+(2 * pi.* freqs).*params(1).*params(4)))...
    ./((1-(2.* pi.* freqs).^2.*params(1).*params(7).*params(6).*params(4)).^2 +((2.* pi.* freqs).*params(7).*params(4)+ (2.* pi.* freqs).*params(7).*params(6)+(2.* pi.* freqs).*params(1).*params(4)).^2),...
    hh  +((2.* pi.* freqs).*params(5).*params(3).^2)./(params(3).^2 + (2.* pi.* freqs).^2.*params(5).^2)...
    -(params(4).*((2 * pi.* freqs).*params(7).*Rp+ (2 * pi.* freqs).*params(7).*params(6)+(2 * pi.* freqs).*params(1).*params(4)) - ((2.* pi.* freqs).*params(7).*params(6).*params(4))...
    .*(1-(2.* pi.* freqs).^2.*params(1).*params(7).*params(6).*params(4)))...
    ./((1-(2.* pi.* freqs).^2.*params(1).*params(7).*params(6).*params(4)).^2 ...
    + ((2.* pi.* freqs).*params(7).*params(4)+ (2.* pi.* freqs).*params(7).*params(6)+(2.* pi.* freqs).*params(1).*params(4)).^2)];
```

but the new errors are:

```
Local minimum possible.

lsqnonlin stopped because the final change in the sum of squares relative to 
its initial value is less than the default value of the function tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>
```

I tried to set the tolerance:

```
options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin,'Algorithm','trust-region-reflective','OptimalityTolerance',1e-8);
```

but it did not work. any suggestions?
the test data is attached.
thanks in advance[image: datalink]

Comment: The error message begins with "Not enough input arguments.", could you verify this?

Comment: @JamesPhillips, thanks for you reply! the "Not enough input arguments" problem has been solved and the post has been renewed. but the new error about the 'tolerance' just showed, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I personally do not use matlab, and cannot advise.